# How to do desambiguation with Flow types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I got simple types, as:

```
type A = { a: number }
type B = { b: string }
```

And I have some wrapper with a `type` for ambiguity:

```
type HasType<T> = {
  node: T,
  type: 'a' | 'b',
}
```

I'm trying to make a `factory` method where it will make that disambiguity to use the following:

```
function onlyA(obj: A): A { return obj; }
function onlyB(obj: B): B { return obj; }
```

Without types, the `factory`  could look like this:

```
function factory(obj) {
  if (obj.type === 'a') onlyA(obj.node)
  else onlyB(obj.node)
}
```

So I've tried a few things,

1. union with `HasType`:

   ```
   function factory(obj: HasType<A> | HasType<B>): void {
     if (obj.type === 'a') onlyA(obj.node)
     else onlyB(obj.node)
   }
   ```
2. union **only** with the types, and access their properties:

   ```
   function factory2(obj: A | B): void {
     if (obj.a) onlyA(obj)
     else onlyB(obj)
   }
   ```
3. union **only** with types, and verify property existence:

   ```
   function factory3(obj: A | B): void {
     if ('a' in obj) onlyA(obj)
     else onlyB(obj)
   }
   ```

Unfortunately, they didn't work, the example can be found [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGm0wGdhiBLLAcygF8AoUSKAIQWSgKo16DclkF1GLVu3DQAEqkoAVWQB4lAPl5JWUbAHsAJhExLSuqBxNQA5KhtQAPrYI3zbVgDMcWAMbBafSwoIIAbEBgACn0CACtMGABKBL5iCGAcYmCY2IBuKW8-AKCQrHCuaLjMLmTuVPTM7Lj8j0L-QODPVH99YhBK+KgFZTUYLWdhlUhVLg1agDd9WkNkC1pPKAGAOisEeEQ7G0TS8KicrawjCESLCFDKaDCQCvPL4xvWn3aSrp6+gCYBilnDVMItlqs9OtNudUMcnmc4jc9HcHidngMPtI2sVOt1gL0QABmIGwJzcBZLFY6KEbSKHKD0EJI9GI2LIqCox5lDE5D5AA).

Am I missing something?
Can we achieve this in a different way?

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions ?

Comment: I've looked at that sooooo many times, and always came up with a disambiguation property (as `type` in `HasType`), only now noticed that the `type` is defined in each type instead of a single one with all the options ... thank you very much. if you want to make a proper response I'll approve it!

Answer (score 1):

The solution as @zerkms points out, is to have the common property in each type, with the specific value, like this:

```
type A = { a: number, type: "a" }
type B = { b: string, type: "b" }

function onlyA(obj: A): A { return obj; }
function onlyB(obj: B): B { return obj; }

function factory(obj: A | B): void {
  if (obj.type === 'a') onlyA(obj)
  else onlyB(obj)
}
```

This can be tested [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGilEkwCJVqoBfAKEugCEFkoDMBnYYgEssAc3KsaBesyYAzHFgDGwQQHssUdQBsQMABSqCAK0wwAlKa7EIwHMQ2GjAbkZyFytQ6w62B45jYLKA4Ua1t7TWMXGXklFXUoWVRlVWIQPxNYKAAfYKCAN1VBABNkJigoQVkoDIA6VgR4RAByVGazTW9dDLNyqAgtXmhtEF9HXuYgA)